# How to convert multiple node in Json format to use in Apps?

Tags: services, 8

I have created a custom module which takes post argument and sent the result in json format.

```
function cfood_api_get_stadium_list($cn, $city){
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
            ->entityCondition('bundle', 'stadium')
            ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
            ->fieldCondition('field_address', 'country', $cn, 'LIKE')
            ->fieldCondition('field_address', 'locality', $city, 'LIKE')
            ->execute();        
    $results = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node']));
    $r = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($results as $result){
        $r[$i]['title'] = $result->title; 
        $r[$i]['nid'] = $result->nid; 
        $r[$i]['type'] = $result->type; 
        $r[$i]['field_image'] = $result->field_image; 
        $r[$i]['field_restaurantss'] = $result->field_restaurantss; 
        $r[$i]['field_address'] = $result->field_address; 
        $r[$i]['field_wing_no'] = $result->field_wing_no; 
        $i++;
    }
    if(empty($results)){
       $results['error'] = "No record found";
    }
    return drupal_json_encode($r);   
}
```

In postman the result looks ok but in apps additional "\" comes like

```
["[{\"vid\":\"74\",\"uid\":\"1\",\"title\":\"Stadium1\",\"log\":\"\",\"status\":\"1\",\"comment\":\"1\",\"promote\":\"0\",\"sticky\":\"0\",\"nid\":\"74\",\"type\":\"stadium\",\"language\":\"und\",\"created\":\"1451888078\",\"changed\":\"1453726703\",\"tnid\":\"0\",\"translate\":\"0\",\"revision_timestamp\":\"1453726703\",\"revision_uid\":\"1\",\"field_image\":{\"und\":[{\"fid\":\"85\",\"uid\":\"1\",\"filename\":\"tennis.jpg\",\"uri\":\"public:\\/\\/tennis.jpg\",\"filemime\":\"image\\/jpeg\",\"filesize\":\"16638\",\"status\":\"1\",\"timestamp\":\"1451888078\",\"rdf_mapping\":[],\"alt\":\"\",\"title\":\"\",\"width\":\"350\",\"height\":\"230\"}]},\"field_restaurantss\":{\"und\":[{\"target_id\":\"6\"},{\"target_id\":\"5\"},{\"target_id\":\"4\"},{\"target_id\":\"77\"},{\"target_id\":\"75\"}]},\"field_address\":{\"und\":[{\"country\":\"IN\",\"administrative_area\":\"DL\",\"sub_administrative_area\":null,\"locality\":\"Delhi\",\"dependent_locality\":\"\",\"postal_code\":\"110014\",\"thoroughfare\":\"Jawaharlal Nehru Stadium\",\"premise\":\"\",\"sub_premise\":null,\"organisation_name\":null,\"name_line\":null,\"first_name\":null,\"last_name\":null,\"data\
```

How to remove this addition "\" . Am i missing something.

Comment: Your code have no errors and should return well formatted json object, may be post man adding these qoutes try that its better than postman,  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: @Mhmdgomma thanks for reply. Actually i am not getting any additional "/" in postman. its looking on in post man. Issue in when the link access in APPS.

Comment: You probably need to set the `Content-type` header to `application/json` using `drupal_add_http_header()`